# Scriptella: transferring data from sql to java

Tags: java, sql, scriptella

Is it possible in scriptella to get the data using sql request and access it into java code? 
Something like following:

```
    <connection id="metadata" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testDB" driver="scriptella.driver.postgresql.Driver" user="user" password="password" classpath="postgresql.jar"/>

    <connection id="java" driver="scriptella.driver.janino.Driver"/>

    <query connection-id="metadata">
        SELECT dataid FROM header_table;
        <query connection-id="java">
            System.out.println(?{dataid});
        </query>
    </query>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is possible in Janino or other scripting languages like JEXL or JS. Since Java is statically typed, you have to use get('name') method for accessing the variable:

```
<connection id="metadata" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testDB" user="user" password="password" classpath="postgresql.jar"/>

<connection id="java" driver="janino"/>

<query connection-id="metadata">
    SELECT dataid FROM header_table;
    <script connection-id="java">
       Object dataId = get("dataid"); 
       System.out.println(dataId);
    </script>
</query>
```

[Janino driver JavaDoc](http://scriptella.javaforge.com/docs/api/scriptella/driver/janino/package-summary.html.) provides more details.